# Is Geneivat Da'at forbidden for Bnei Noach?

Tags: noahidism, genaivas-daas

Since the Bnei Noach are forbidden to steal, is Geneivat Da'at also forbidden for them?

Comment: A quick search on Bar Ilan proved fruitless.

Comment: Does this beg questions about the application of the word "geneivah" here? Does one have to pay kefel? Can one ever return the item stolen? Is there gezeilat da'at?

Comment: Even according to those who hold gezel akum is mutar, the Taz says that Geneivas daas of Akum is assur. Not sure if that makes a difference to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128063/may-a-gentile-look-like-a-jew/128085#128085) on a related question:

R. Shim'on Sofer (grandson of the Hatham Sofer) has a responsum ([התעוררות תשובה סי' קי"ח](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1769&pgnum=93)) in which he expresses uncertainty about whether a gentile is bound to uphold the prohibition against גניבת דעת but seems to lean towards yes. The determination hinges on whether the prohibition is to be categorized as rabbinic or biblical. If it is biblical, then it falls under לא תגנובו (thou shalt not steal) and would therefore be part of the Noahide covenant gentiles are bound to uphold. If however the prohibition is rabbinic, then it is not a part of the Noahide laws and a gentile would not be bound to uphold it.